# Hide variable application result from bash output

Tags: bash, variables, stdout

I am trying to create a script that will run wget to a few sites and check if we receive a 200 OK from the site.

My problem is that the result of wget application is shown in the stdout. Is there a way I can hide this.

My current script is:

```
RESULT=`wget -O wget.tmp http://mysite.com 2>&1`
```

Later I will use regex to look for the 200 OK we receive from the errout that wget produces.
When I run the script, it works fine, but I get the result of the wget added between my echos.

Any way around this?

Comment: Your command works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RESULT=`wget --spider http://mysite.com 2>&1`
```

And this does the trick too:

```
RESULT=`wget -O wget.tmp http://mysite.com >/dev/null 2>&1`
```

Played around a little and came up with that one:

```
RESULT=`curl -fSw "%{http_code}" http://example.com/ -o a.tmp 2>/dev/null`
```

This outputs nothing but "200" - Nothing else.

Comment: Jack, I'm not seeing backticks or `$( ... )`?

Comment: I just tried both, but I still get the stderr to output to my screen as. I am starting to think that this might be wget as it looks like it is only showing you the stderr when you run it by itself...

Answer (score 0):

Jack's [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602542/hide-variable-application-result-from-bash-output/3602562#3602562) are good.  I'd modify them just slightly.

If you only need to check the status code, use the `--spider` option that Jack referenced.  From the docs:

> When invoked with this option, Wget will behave as a Web spider, which means that it will not download the pages, just check that they are there.

And Jack's second suggestion shows the core ideas behind hiding output:

```
... >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The above redirects standard output to `/dev/null`.  The `2>&1` then redirects standard error to the current standard output file descriptor, which has already been redirected to `/dev/null`, so it won't give you any output.

But, since you don't want output, you might be able to use the `--quiet` option.  From the docs:

> Turn off Wget's output.

So, I'd probably use the following command

```
wget --quiet --spider 'http://mysite.com/your/page'
if [[ $? != 0 ]] ; then
    # error retrieving page, do something useful
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TCP_HOST="mydomain.com"
TCP_PORT=80
exec 5<>/dev/tcp/"${TCP_HOST}"/"${TCP_PORT}"
echo -e "HEAD / HTTP/1.0\nHOST:${TCP_HOST}\n" >&5
while read -r line
do
    case "$line" in
        *200*OK* )
            echo "site OK:$TCP_HOST"
            exec >&5-
            exit
           ;;
        *) echo "site:$TCP_HOST not ok"
           ;;
    esac
done <&5
```